# Enyo custom properties

Tags: javascript, properties, enyo

I try to create my own kind in enyo

```
enyo.kind(
{
    name: "DeviceButton",
    kind: "Button",
    caption: "",
    published: { userAgent: "" },
    flex: 1,
    onclick: "butclick",
    butclick: function() { console.log("User agent changed to " + this.userAgent) }
})
```

But when I click there is nothing shown

If I just did

```
onclick: console.log("User agent changed to " + this.userAgent)
```

It was printed that this.userAgent is undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Btw., is it possible to send parameters via onclick (so that the function repsponding to the click get a variable)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having here is that the onclick property is actually giving the name of the event handler for the Enyo to send the event to when the click is received. The "butclick" event isn't dispatched to the DeviceButton, but rather to its parent.

If you want to handle the event entirely within your kind, then you need to set it up as a "handler". In Enyo 2.x, you do it like this:

```
enyo.kind(
{
    name: "DeviceButton",
    kind: "Button",
    caption: "",
    published: { userAgent: "" },
    flex: 1,
    handlers {
      onclick: "butclick"
    },
    butclick: function() { console.log("User agent changed to " + this.userAgent) }
})
```

In Enyo 1.x, you'd just need to name the handler function "onclickHandler". I mention the Enyo 1 solution because I see that you have "flex: 1" in your definition. Flexbox isn't supported in Enyo 2, we have a "Fittable" system instead.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little example for you how enyo can handle sending and receiving values to and from a custom kind. I also added some short comments inside the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/K3azX/

```
enyo.kind({
    name: 'App',
    kind: enyo.Control,
    components: [
        {kind:'FittableRows', components:[
            // calls the custom kind by it's default values
            {kind:'DeviceButton',name:'bttn1', classes:'joop-btn',ontap:'printToTarget'},
            // calls the custom kind and pass the variables to the DeviceButton kind
            {kind:'DeviceButton', name:'bttn2', btnstring:'Get Agent', useragent:'chrome', classes:'joop-btn', ontap:'printToTarget'},
            {tag:'div', name:'targetContainer', content:'no button clicked yet', classes:'joop-target'},
        ]},                
    ],
    printToTarget:function(inSender, inEvent){
        // inSender = the button that was pressed
        this.$.targetContainer.setContent(inSender.name+' has used the value: "'+inSender.getUseragent()+'" and sends the value of: "'+inSender.getValueToPrint()+'" back.');  
    },

});

enyo.kind({
    name:'DeviceButton',
    kind:enyo.Control,
    components:[
        {kind:'onyx.Button',name:'btn', ontap:'printUsrAgent'}
    ],
    published:{
        btnstring:'default btnstring', // value that will be received
        useragent:'default useragent',  // value that will be received
        valueToPrint:'default valueToPrint' // value that will be used 
    },
    rendered:function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.$.btn.setContent(this.btnstring);
    },
    printUsrAgent:function(inSender,inEvent){
        // set a parameter with the value that was received of if not received use the default value (normaly would do some calculations with it first)
        this.valueToPrint = this.useragent+' after changes'; 
    },
});
​
```